# Sci-fi movie about a guy who wakes up from a truck accident, has lost his memory, and anybody who gets within 150 yards of him drops dead

Tags: story-identification, movie

What is this sci-fi movie about a guy who wakes up from a truck accident, has lost his memory, and anybody who gets within 150 yards of him drops dead? Then he meets a woman who nullifies his toxicity, and then there's a twist I won't divulge and ruin it.

Comment: For future reference, '*hiding the twist*' just makes it harder for people to find the right answer. The correct thing to do is to put it behind a spoiler tag like this >!

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. Unregistered users are not able to vote, and they would not be able to respond to or edit posts made under the same username on another device or browser, or when their browser cookies are cleared. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Comment: Thank you . . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [**Radius**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6097798/) (2017).

> A man wakes up with no memory of who he is, and finds that everyone
> who comes within a certain distance of him suddenly dies.

Comment: YES! Thank you! It's on Amazon . . .

Comment: @SDavies - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: Hey, it's the dude from "Blacklist".